# Allow sudo only to run one Python script that accesses GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, sudo

I have a simple Python script that controls three LEDs. I want to limit the `sudo` command for my user *counter* (member of group *pimem*) to just run this script and because it access the GPIOs also allow `/dev/mem/`. I am connecting to my Pi with *tigervnc*.

In my `/etc/sudoers` file I added the following to the end:

```
#Allow group members to run scripts in dirs of counter
counter ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/python /home/counter/Desktop/piCam.py

#Allow users of group pimem to access /dev/mem
%pimem ALL=(ALL) /dev/mem/
```

My script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# ./piCam.py -f 40
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time

frequency = 50 #Hz
dutyCycle = 10 # 0.0 - 100.0

LED_1 = 11
LED_2 = 13
LED_3 = 15

def mainArgs(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        return -1
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(argv)):
            arg = argv[i]
            if arg == '-f':
                frequency = int(argv[i+1])
                print("f = ", frequency)
            if arg == '-d':
                dutyCycle = int(argv[i+1])
                print("d = ", dutyCycle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainArgs(sys.argv)

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.cleanup()
    GPIO.setwarnings(True)

    GPIO.setup(LED_1, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(LED_2, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(LED_3, GPIO.OUT)

    print("Lights on")

    PIN_1 = GPIO.PWM(LED_1, frequency)
    PIN_1.start(dutyCycle)
    PIN_2 = GPIO.PWM(LED_2, frequency)
    PIN_2.start(dutyCycle)
    PIN_3 = GPIO.PWM(LED_3, frequency)
    PIN_3.start(dutyCycle)

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            #Wait for user to take photo
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")

    PIN_1.stop()
    PIN_2.stop()
    PIN_3.stop()

    GPIO.cleanup()

    print("Done")
```

But when running I get the following error:

```
Sorry, user counter is not allowed to execute './piCam.py' as root on PiCellCounter.
```

How can I run this script with `sudo` but not more?

Comment: If you type in `/home/counter/Desktop/piCam.py` does that work?

Comment: @joan I have to try tomorrow, I have currently changed to sudo wheel and installing quite a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Con,  just wondering why if you only want root to be able to run the script you can't just use chown to change the ownership of the file.    Have I misunderstood your requirement?    If not it would be something like:

```
    sudo chown root:root nameOfFile.py
```

Comment: Nowadays there is no need to use sudo to access the GPIO via RPi.GPIO anyhow - as long as Raspbian jessie is being used.